# jquery image gallery showing loader gif

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing jquery image gallery plugin.
I checked loading of the image like this:

```
$("#loading").show();
        $('.preview').load(function () {
            $("#loading").hide();
        });
```

But I didnt success.
I want to show loading gif when  my image is loaded.How can I do this? For ex:
http://blueimp.github.com/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/

Answer (score 0):

You can simple give it through css. Try giving the loading image as background for the parent div